# Android GPS getLastKnownLocation if locationUpdater takes too long

Tags: android, gps, location, locationlistener

with android and using GPS as a location provider, how can I tell it to stop looking for a GPS lock after a specified number of seconds and simply resort to using the last known location instead?

I am currently doing it the other way around, where I get the lask known location first, and then let the request update function run. My problem with this is that the GPS will sometimes NEVER get a fix, but it doesn't stop trying to get a fix. Very annoying issue to me (and probably to some users)

suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a code where you create LocationListener and start listening for location updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can use a Timer for this. you can follow below steps.

1. Define a TimerTask that will unregister the Location listener and  get the lask known location.
2. Before registering the Location listener , define and schedule a timer with the above TimerTask and a delay say 60000 miliseconds  (Your timeout period). Use the below method for schedule.

   ```
   public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay)   
   e.g. timer1.schedule(timerTask,60000)
   ```

This should stop the location listener after 60 seconds as you are unregistering it in the timertask. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

When you unregister your location listener, it should stop trying to get a fix. Please see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29) link for a reference. I also had this issue with a recent application of mine, and unregistering the listener worked.